# Mvvmcross xamarin forms button command inside Listview template

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have viewmodel and view which lists my Model objects in ListView and each of list entries contains 2 buttons: details and reservation.

View

```
    <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Delete}"></Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Details}"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
              
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
   class ModelsViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Model> models;
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models
        {
            get
            {
                return models;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref models, value);
            }
        }

        private IMvxCommand details;
        public IMvxCommand Details
        {
            get
            {
                details = details ?? new MvxCommand<ListItem>(o =>
                {

                });
                return details;
            }
        }

        private IMvxCommand delete;
        public IMvxCommand Delete
        {
            get
            {
                delete = delete ?? new MvxCommand<ListItem>(o =>
                {

                });
                return delete;
            }
        }
    }
```

Each of those buttons should invoke the lambda in Details/Delete methods in ModelsViewModel.

What happens though is the databinding in listview points to Model objects where no such methods exists. My question is, is there a way to change the binding context of the items in listview, and  pass the items clicked as paremeter?

I tried messing up with Source and setting BindingContext with no success

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="parentContePage">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentContePage}, Path=BindingContext.Delete}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentContePage}, Path=BindingContext.Details}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </StackLayout>                
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Make sure to give `x:Name` to your parent content page as written above.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not fix the problem. Nothing happens when the buttons are clicked.  My quess is Mvvmcross might not support that feature, or i am yet to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, I can comment yet so I will post an answer instead.
Try to change the command from `MvxCommand<ListItem>` to `MvxCommand<Model>`, since the command parameter took the current model after following the previous answer.